# How to store combo box and radio button values to mysql database using php script?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to insert data into mysql database using php script. **I have inserted text box values like: fname, lname, email and pwd.**
In this case I have 2 problems. The First one is I can't to assign for variable and store the combo box and radio button values.
The Second one is how can to store the apart values of combo box into one like: Month, Day and Year into the database. How can I do that?
My **Database** attributes are: "**fname, lname, userpasswd, username, bdate, sex**"
Thanks!

This is snapshot of my Registration Form

```
  <form name="signup" action="actions/registeruser.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate()">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="fname">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your Email" maxlength="30" size="45" name="email">
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" maxlength="15" size="45" name="pwd">
    <select name="month" size="">
        <option>Month</option>
        <option>jan</option>
        <option>feb</option>
        <option>mar</option>
    </select>
    <select name="Day" size="">
        <option>Day</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <select name="Year" size="">
        <option>Year</option>
        <option>2013</option>
        <option>2012</option>
        <option>2011</option>
    </select><br /><br />
    <input type="radio" name="sex" checked="checked">Male
    <input type="radio" name="sex" >Female
    <input type="submit" value="Sin Up" >
    </form><hr width="2">
```

This is snapshot of the 'registeruser.php' file

```
<?php
    session_start();

$dbhost="localhost";
$dbuser="root";
$dbpass="";
$tablename="users";
//connect the server & select database
$conn=mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)or die("cannor connect");
mysql_select_db('fb')or die("cannort select DB");

// user details sent from FORM
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $password=$_POST['pwd'];
    $mail=$_POST['email'];
//Register Students 
$sql="INSERT INTO $tablename(fname, lname, userpasswd, usermail)values('$fname','$lname', '$password','$mail')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

    if($result){
    echo "<font size='+1' color='blue'> $fname, Successfully Registered.</font>";

    }
    else
    {

    echo "<font size='+1' color='red'>Registration Failed.</font>"; 

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add 'value' property to your 'option's.
For "Month" options, it should be like this

```
<option value="">Month</option>
<option value="01">jan</option>
<option value="02">feb</option>
<option value="03">mar</option>
```

For "Day" options, it should be like this

```
<option value="">Day</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
```

And also, for "Year" options, it should be like this

```
<option value="">Year</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
```

In the case of radio button, you also need to add 'value' property

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked="checked">Male
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" >Female
```

At the PHP side, you can get POST data like this

```
$date = $_POST["Year"] . "-" . $_POST["month"] . "-" . $_POST["Day"];
$sex = $_POST["sex"];
```

Answer (score 0):

To store a date in your MySQL database, you'll need to concatenate the individual year, month and day fields using something like this:

```
$date = sprintf("%04d%02d%02d", $year, $month, $day);
```

This will produce a date with a structure like `20130805` which is how MySQL expects a date, and you can subsequently store it in your `bdate`field.

As for passing along the values of your `select` elements to PHP - don't forget to set a `value` attribute for each `option` element.

Answer (score 0):

For fields fname, lname, password and email choose nvarchar in table and store them by they're real value. But For the fields bdate, sex, I suggest to define datetime and tinyint.

In your application, you can use [JQuery jui datetime picker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) for your bdate, and for fields sex you did right. After submitting the form by user, you have to convert the datetime by:

```
$bdate=date(Y-m-d h:m:s,$_POST['bdate']);
```

and for the sex field just store its value as an integer value as so:

```
$sex=$_POST['sex'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Dear friend the answer to the first question is that you club together the three seperate fields into one variable like this :

```
$date = $_POST['Year'].':'.$_POST['month'].':'.$_POST['Day'];
```

Now you will get the date in the format as, for eg : '2013:jan:1' . You can store it in a text field or string field in mysql database. For you to store it in date type column in mysql you need some formatting to be done to the date variable.

Now inorder to get the gender its very simple :

```
$gender = $_POST['sex'];
```

Now make sure that the 'bday' ans 'sex' columns in your mysql databse to be of string type or character type. (with at least size 10 for bday and size 6 for sex).

So the registeruser.php could be modified to :

```
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];
$password=$_POST['pwd'];
$mail=$_POST['email'];
$bdate = $_POST['Year'].':'.$_POST['month'].':'.$_POST['Day'];
$gender = $_POST['sex'];

//Register Students 
$sql="INSERT INTO $tablename(fname, lname, userpasswd, usermail,bdate,sex)values('$fname','$lname', '$password','$mail','$bdate','$gender')";

$result=mysql_query($sql);
```